# C++ linkage error

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I compile in Visual studio 2008 and get this error.  I have researched linkage error but am still uncertain to what it is.  This is the finished code to a poker game so I would rather not post the code.  Can someone translate this error message for me?

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "`void __cdecl betFold(double)`" (?betFold@@YAXN@Z) referenced in function "`void __cdecl flopAction(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)`" (`?flopAction@@YAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z`)    OH-DLL.obj

Comment: where is `betFold(double)`, can you figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `void flopAction(std::string arg)` uses a function `betFold(double)` that gets referenced and declared in some header, but is not implemented so that the linker is able to find it.

Comment: OK betFold is declared by void betFold(double BetSize);
and it is defined further down in the same header file as
void BetFold(double BetSize) 
{
   //code
}
the linker finds all other functions in that header declared the same way.  Any clue to reasons why this is special?

Comment: Maybe try `void betFold(double BetSize) {`?

Comment: Can you tell me what makes the linker be able to find a function?

Comment: The linker distinguisches the case of the identifier of the function!

Comment: I hate myself, it was a capitalization error.  I swear i checked it 5 times.  Thanks for the help. 1 more reputation and i could upvote you

Answer (score 3):

It means that you have *declared* this method but not defined it. Or at least the linker cannot find the definition, either because it’s in a library that you didn’t reference or else because it’s in an object file (source file) that is not part of your build process.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you forgot to specify the *.lib file that belongs to the *.dll. You can edit the list under your Project Property Pages -> Configuration properties -> Linker -> Input, remember to do this for the Debug and Release configuration.

And please try to refrain from phrases like wtf etc :)

Answer (score -1):

Also, you could check your signature(function declaration), so that it contains only the type in it's parameter lists, while inside the definition(.cpp file), it contains both the type and parameter names. For eg,

in the .h file where the declaration sits:

```
void myfunc(int, char*);
```

and in the .cpp file where the definition sits:

```
void myfunc(int num, char* name)
{
 //
}
```

I learnt this before in my college, but don't sure if Dev C++ supports it, left this things for a long time ago, just using Borland at that time.

hope this helps.
thanks.

Comment: VS2008 doesn't care about parameter names when linking.